# Getting wrong/misleading info related to oracle table index

Tags: oracle, index, plsql

1. Creating a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "HOTEL3" 
   (    "NAMEX" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
    "PRICE" NUMBER, 
    "ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) DEFAULT sys_guid()
   );
```

2. Creating an index as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX "IDX_HOTEL3_CITY_NAME" ON "HOTEL3" ("CITY" ASC, "NAMEX" DESC);
```

3. Querying the index information:

```
SELECT *
FROM   all_ind_columns ic
WHERE  ic.index_owner = 'FOO'
    AND ic.table_name = 'HOTEL3'
ORDER  BY ic.column_position;
```

I am getting the below result (csv)

```
"INDEX_OWNER","INDEX_NAME","TABLE_OWNER","TABLE_NAME","COLUMN_NAME","COLUMN_POSITION","COLUMN_LENGTH","CHAR_LENGTH","DESCEND","COLLATED_COLUMN_ID"
"FOO","IDX_HOTEL3_CITY_NAME","FOO","HOTEL3","CITY",1,4000,4000,"ASC",
"FOO","IDX_HOTEL3_CITY_NAME","FOO","HOTEL3","SYS_NC00005$",2,2000,0,"DESC",
```

Observe the second record; `COLUMN_NAME` is `SYS_NC00005$` instead of `NAMEX`.

Here are a few side notes. After step #1 if you query `all_tab_cols` you get all 4 columns. However, after step #2, `all_tab_cols` now has an additional entry - the same name as shown above query result. This could be far-fetched; but the `ID` field having `DEFAULT` set may be why, after step #2, `all_tab_cols` has that strange entry.

So what query can I issue to get the correct index information?

PS: oracle server is 19c I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you defined `NAMEX` as `DESC`, Oracle creates a function-based index using `SYS_OP_DESCEND` on an internally hidden `RAW` column that you can see in `all_tab_cols` (not `all_tab_columns`). The index is on this `RAW` column which has a system-generated name. `all_ind_expressions` will show you the expression that will be passed into these functions, indicating the column name.

Any time you have any kind of function-based index you have to go to `*_ind_expressions` to get the actual definition and swap out the system-named column with this expression to represent what you expect.

Now this cannot be done in SQL because that would require working with LONGs, which SQL can do very little with. There is a workaround, however using PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE all_ind_expressions_rectype IS OBJECT (
COLUMN_EXPRESSION   VARCHAR2(4000),
COLUMN_POSITION NUMBER
)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE all_ind_expressions_tabtype IS TABLE OF all_ind_expressions_rectype
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_all_ind_expressions_ext(in_index_owner IN varchar2, in_index_name IN varchar2)
  RETURN all_ind_expressions_tabtype PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
  FOR rec_expr IN (SELECT *
                     FROM all_ind_expressions
                    WHERE index_owner = in_index_owner
                      AND index_name = in_index_name)
  LOOP
    DECLARE
      var_column_expression varchar2(4000);
    BEGIN
      var_column_expression := rec_expr.column_expression;
      PIPE ROW(all_ind_expressions_rectype(var_column_expression,rec_expr.column_position));
    END;
  END LOOP;
  
  RETURN;
END;  
/
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_ind_expressions_ext
AS
SELECT i.owner index_owner,
       i.index_name,
       i.table_owner,
       i.table_name,
       x.*
  FROM all_indexes i
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_all_ind_expressions_ext(i.owner,i.index_name)) x
 ORDER BY table_owner,table_name,index_owner,index_name,column_position       
/
```

Now you may use `all_ind_expressions_ext` in your SQL and use the expression in any function you'd like (`CASE`, `REPLACE`, `WHERE` clause, `LISTAGG`, anything).

Comment: I think this answer need to be enhanced a little bit, though what I am asking further is not exactly in scope of this question.  It may not be apparent to a novicer like me. Assume that `all_ind_cols` is labeled as `ic` and `all_ind_expressions` is labeled as `ie`. I cannot do a `CASE WHEN IC.COLUMNAME LIKE 'SYS_NC%' THEN IE.COLUMN_EXPRESSION ELSE IC.COLUMN_NAME END`. Getting an `ORA-00932` error.

Comment: @deostroll, you can't work with LONGs like that. You'd have to create a pipelined function that uses PL/SQL to assign the `COLUMN_EXPRESSION` to a local `varchar2(4000)` in a record type and pipe it, then you can query the function and work with `COLUMN_EXPRESSION` as a normal `varchar2`. That's the frustrating reality of Oracle's historical use of LONGs in its dictionary. But once you get this technique down you can create wrapper functions around any of these dictionary objects.

Comment: @deostroll - I enhanced my answer with code to wrap the view and expose `COLUMN_EXPRESSION` as a `varchar2`.

Comment: Didn't know it was this complex. But thanks. 

Answer (score 2):

That is how an index on a column defined with descending order is defined.

You can find the actual expression in the `COLUMN_EXPRESSION` column of the `ALL_IND_EXPRESSIONS` view.